# Exponential function passing through two points with arbitrary slope

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I want an exponential function which passes through `(0,p)` and `(n-1,1-p)`, where `p` is a constant in range `[0,1]`. The following function met this requirement:
$$y = p\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{\frac{x}{n-1}}$$

But I want to include another variable `s` in `[0,1]` in this function which controls the slope (derivative) of the function. How can I change the function to include this variable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You can define another function with different slopes that goes through the same two points, but it won't be an exponential function. Which of your requirements (two points, exponential, choice of slope) can you drop?

Comment: @DavidK I can drop the exponential requirement, but I do not want a function which crosses `y=0.5` always at the same `x`. I want a function where for smaller `p`, the function cross `y=0.5` at greater `x`, like the function that I presented in the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: $x(x-n+1)$ is zero at the endpoints so you could muck about with multiplying by $f(s)^{ x(x-n+1)}$ or adding $f(s)*{ x(x-n+1)}$.

Comment: @user121049 Thanks. Seems a good idea. I'll investigate it.